# Flutter state management

Tags: flutter, state-management

If I only want a widget and its children have specific Provider but not in whole app, how do I achieve that ?

```
// not this
  void main() {
     runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CartModel()),
        Provider(create: (context) => SomeOtherClass()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
       ),
     );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to  wrap `MultiProvider` to the Widget you want.
Like this:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MultiProvider(
        providers: [Provider(create: (context) => TestModel(index: 1)),],
        child: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page')
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap this widget with the provider and can be used as

```
final _myProvider=Provider.of<MyProvider>(context, listen: false);
```

or using

```
Consumer<MyProvider>(
 builder: (BuildContext context, MyProvider myProvider, Widget child) {
   return child;
),
```